# jquery ( each and eq ) usage together in switch

Tags: jquery, indexing, each

question 1:
i am trying to manipulate same classed div element's css to their order with eq() but i cant access the eq() value.

question 2:
tried this with switch method. is there a way to do this progress with lesser code like for loop?

[this is DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Aw39W/7/)

HTML

```
<div id="a" class="ele">0</div>
<div id="b" class="ele">1</div>
<div id="c" class="ele">2</div>
```

​
jQuery

```
$('.ele').each(function() {
var eleH = 100;
var add = 10;

 $('.ele').eq(X); //trying to get value here

 switch(X) {
  case 0:
    $('.ele').css({'height': (eleH + add) + 'px'}); // #a { height:110px}
    break;
  case 1:
    $('.ele').css({'height': (eleH + (add*2)) + 'px'}); // #b { height:120px}
    break;
  case 2:
    $('.ele').css({'height': (eleH + (add*3)) + 'px'}); // #c { height:130px}
    break;
 }

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what do you want to do, but if you want to change CSS propierty according its position you can do it like this:

```
$('.ele').each(function(i) {
    $(this).css('height', 100 + (10*i));
});
```

Here is the working version: http://jsfiddle.net/Aw39W/6/

Answer (score 2):

check this http://jsfiddle.net/Aw39W/4/

your are not assign the value for X and project

```
$('.ele').each(function(X) {
    var eleH = 100;
    var add = 10;
    
    $('.ele').eq(X); //trying to get value here

    switch(X) {
      case 0:
        $(this).css({'height': (eleH + add) + 'px'}); // #a { height:110px}
        break;
      case 1:
        $(this).css({'height': (eleH + (add*2)) + 'px'}); // #b { height:120px}
        break;
      case 2:
        $(this).css({'height': (eleH + (add*3)) + 'px'}); // #c { height:130px}
        break;
    }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure what you're trying to achieve here, since you seem to be setting the height not on the elements themselves, but on some other element, `project`. Setting and overwriting its height 3 times in quick succession will simply look like only the final loop iteration took place.

In any case, on a point of theory, your code can be optimised like so. It's good to remember that `each()` is passed a param, denoting the index of the element being handled.

```
var height = 100, add = 10;
$('.ele').each(index) {
    project.css({height: height + (add * index)});
});
```

Note also I declare the dimension vars outside the loop - no need to keep redefining these.

Comment: i forgot to declare var project = $('.ele') , but my biggest mistake was not using $(this)